# Uploadify and PHP FTP - $_REQUEST['folder'] not getting passed

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I am trying to use uploadify and an FTP connection to upload a file. I realized the directories weren't being created because the 'folder' var from the js is not getting passed. I am wondering if this is a scope thing. Anyway, here is the js:

```
$("#uploadify").uploadify({
'uploader'       : '/lib/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.0/uploadify.swf',
'script'         : '/lib/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.0/uploadify.php',
'cancelImg'      : '/lib/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.0/example/cancel.png',
'folder'         : '<?=time()?>',
'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
'multi'          : true
```

});

PHP:

```
$dir = $_REQUEST['folder'];
if (!ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dir)) {
 echo "There was a problem while creating $dir\n";
} else {
echo "successfully created $dir\n";
}
```

I get an error-- "ftp_mkdir(): Unable to create the directory."

I did check to see if the time() was getting echoed out and it is. If I hardcode a plain string there it fails. But if I change the $dir to equal "whatever" (rather than request) the directory will get created, but it will not take the request param. I tried get and post as well.

Also this same scenario does work if I am not using FTP, just upload to server the page is being served from – no problems.

Comment: What format is the `time` in? It may have invalid characters as far as path names go, that aren't allowed on whatever OS you're using.

Comment: When I echo out time() it's just numbers -- "1284220390".Here is what is even more strange. Without using the ajax, if I go directly to the php file and add ?folder=1284220390 to the URL, the request is picked up and the folder is created. Could it be that time() needs converted to a string or is it already a string?

Comment: Also I could edit folder to: "'folder'         : 'test' "  and it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is an update. The response I am getting Warning: ftp_mkdir(): Unable to create the directory. in /Users/user/Sites/site/lib/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.0/uploadify.php on line 57. There was a problem while creating /send-files/1284224865 

So it is getting passed but I am not sure what the error is about. Like I said if I use time() in the php, it works. Only when the time() is passed through uploadify ajax does it fail.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do to diagnose:

1. Make sure that PHP is accessing the path you think it is accessing.
2. Make sure that `send-files` exists in that path and that it is world writable.

From your error message it looks like you're perhaps running your server on a Linux or Mac box (I'm guessing Mac).  Do you know that the `send-files` directory exists for sure?  You might want to check and make sure that `send-files` is in the current working directory that PHP is using:

```
<?php
print getcwd();
?>
```

Create a file with the code above, visit it in the browser, and if the result is not the same directory/path that actually contains `send-files`, you can do one of two things in the PHP script for uploadify:

1. Change the PHP current working directory to your path for send-files: `chdir('/Users/user/Sites/directory/with/send-files/')`.  You should just be able to put this in at the top of the uploadify PHP script, and it should work.  But if it doesn't, post and I can help you figure out why. ;]
2. Create `send-files` in whatever path results from the `getcwd()` call in the PHP script above.

In either case, you need to make sure that the directory `send-files` exists and that PHP has permissions to write to that directory.  Either one of those options above will help with part one of that, making sure the path exists.

So then we get to part two.  We need to make sure that directory is writable by the PHP script.  We'll `chmod` the files so that they are world writable.  There are at least two ways to do this as well:

1. If you know how to use the command line/Mac's Terminal app, fire it up and `cd` to the directory where `send-files` is located: `cd /Users/user/Sites/path/to/send-files` (but in this example you'd want to `cd` into /to, not /send-files ;])  Then execute this: `chmod -R 777 send-files`
2. If you don't know how to use the command line, LEARN.  It's incredibly useful.  But for now, if you're on a Mac, use Finder to browse to the directory in which `send-files` is located.  Right click on `send-files` and click "Get Info".  At the bottom of the Info pane, expand the "Sharing & Permissions" section.  Click the lock in the lower right corner of the Info pane and enter your password to unlock the permission options so that you can edit them.  Change the each item in the privilege column to the option "Read & Write".  This will make that directory and all of its contents readable/writable.

Then try uploading your files again and see if the file ends up there.  Did it work?